# SQL select pairwise combinations from table meeting predefined criteria

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table that looks similar to the following:

```
+------+----------+----------+------------+
|  id  | group_id |   role   | subject_id |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| A-L1 | A        | leader   |          1 |
| A-F2 | A        | follower |          2 |
| A-F3 | A        | follower |          3 |
| B-L4 | B        | leader   |          4 |
| B-F5 | B        | follower |          5 |
| B-F6 | B        | follower |          6 |
| B-F7 | B        | follower |          7 |
| C-L8 | C        | leader   |          8 |
| C-F9 | C        | follower |          9 |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
```

I want to select pairwise combinations from this table, but only within each group and only those pairwise combinations that involve a "leader" role. Eg. the result should look like this:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| pair_id | leader_id | follower_id |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| A-L1-F2 | A-L1      | A-F2        |
| A-L1-F3 | A-L1      | A-F3        |
| B-L4-F5 | B-L4      | B-F5        |
| B-L4-F6 | B-L4      | B-F6        |
| B-L4-F7 | B-L4      | B-F7        |
| C-L8-F9 | C-L8      | C-F9        |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

Since I will be making this query many times, I would like to turn it into a view. Any suggestions on SQL code I can use for this? I have not tried anything at this point because I am not sure where to start and am just getting started with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using self joins aligned to same *group_id* but different roles with last two tables aligned to *id* and same roles:

```
SELECT t1.id || Replace(t2.id, t2.group_id, '') AS pair_id, 
       t1.id AS leader_id, 
       t3.id AS follower_id
FROM pgTable t1
INNER JOIN pgTable t2 ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id
INNER JOIN pgTable t3 ON t1.group_id = t3.group_id AND t2.id = t3.id
WHERE t1.role = 'leader' AND t2.role = 'follower' AND t3.role = 'follower';
```

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LTJ45955)